# Format custom date using dayjs without using CustomParseFormat

Tags: javascript, date, dayjs

I am currently working on migrating from momentjs to dayjs.

The part that I’m stuck on is that converting an Dayjs object with ISO8601 under strict mode as momentjs does. At first, I tried to convert the object with `CustomParseFormat` like below as [a documentation described](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format). And it returned invalid date object like below because of [issue](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/929) from a bug in `CustomParseFormat`.

```js
const dayjs = require('dayjs');
const customParseFormat = require('dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat')
dayjs.extend(customParseFormat);

// not sure that dayjs is utilizing the format in below for ISO8601
const iso8601Format = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ' 
const currentDate = new Date();
console.log(dayjs(currentDate, iso8601Format, true)); 
// the result is like below 
// {
//    '$L': 'en',
//    '$u': undefined,
//    '$d': Invalid Date,
//    '$y': NaN,
//    '$M': NaN,
//    '$D': NaN,
//    '$W': NaN,
//    '$H': NaN,
//    '$m': NaN,
//    '$s': NaN,
//    '$ms': NaN
// }
```

However, if I converted the object without extending `CustomParseFormat`, it seems like returning an valid object.

```
const dayjs = require('dayjs');

// not sure that dayjs is utilizing the format in below for ISO8601
const iso8601Format = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ' 
const currentDate = new Date();
console.log(dayjs(currentDate, iso8601Format, true));
// the result is like below 
// M {
//  '$L': 'en',
//      '$d': 2022-06-10T02:59:43.585Z,
//      '$x': {},
//  '$y': 2022,
//      '$M': 5,
//      '$D': 10,
//      '$W': 5,
//      '$H': 11,
//      '$m': 59,
//      '$s': 43,
//      '$ms': 585
// }
```

So, my question is that does dayjs allow to parse the date with custom format without using `CustomParseFormat`? Also, does it guarantee that the result is same as momentjs? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are getting `Invalid Date` is because the `iso8601Format` string does not match dayjs's [parsing tokens](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format#list-of-all-available-parsing-tokens). 3-digit milliseconds in dayjs is represented as `SSS`, not `sss`. In addition, the `Z` in dayjs represents offset from UTC, as `-05:00`.

`dayjs(currentDate, iso8601Format, true)` is unnecessary as you can instantiate a dayjs instance directly with `dayjs(currentDate)`. You can also pass in a string in iso8601format like `dayjs("2022-06-10T04:32:08.320Z")` and that will correctly instantiate a dayjs instance. There is no need to use `customParseFormat` unless the string can only be parsed with the parsing tokens.

Comment: oh I got it. that's truly my fault. Thank you for your answer. I have one more question. can I expect that `dayjs(currentDate)` is same as when moment converts Date object to ISO8601 with strict mode? `moment(currentDate, moment.ISO_8601, true)`?

Comment: The resulting date in dayjs should be the same as in momentjs. I don't know if any library can make guarantees as giving the exact same results as another library, but according to the docs this usage should be equivalent